# How to use a variable in vb asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I don't know why the last line of code in this example doesn't work. In default.aspx.vb:

```
Public Var1 As String
```

In a Protected Sub in default.aspx.vb:

```
Var1 = "a"
ModalPopupExtender1.Show()
```

In another Protected Sub in default.aspx.vb:

```
Var1 = "b"
ModalPopupExtender1.Show()
```

And in default.aspx in the Panel of ModalPopupExtender1 for an asp Radiobutton:

```
text = "Beginning of the text " & Var1 & " next of the text"
```

It has to show value a or b here.

Comment: Where exactly is the line `text = ...` executed? If you have it in markup, it will be executed very early, before most of code behindis executed

Comment: In default.aspx, that is the html page.

Comment: Again, markup is parsed and processed very early, at this time Var1 is not set to anything. Move this initializion to some late event in code behind, say to PreRender, and you should be set

Comment: It's now in Partial Class _Default, this has no Prerender. Tried it in Protected Sub Page_PreRender but that is not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "this has no Prerender"? I understood this is just a regular aspx page, which always raises PreRender event. It might not have a handler defined, but you can define one yourself easily

Comment: I meant in code behind, in default.aspx.vb.

Comment: How would you replace  & Var1 & ?

Comment: I'll post an answer to clarify this a bit, perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the fact that markup for .aspx page is parsed very early, somewhere on the initialization stage of a page life cycle. Thus the chages that (presumably) are done to variable Var1 *has not happened yet* when your `text` field is being set in the markup.

To fix this, you should set this field to the code behind. Make sure this time it is executed later in page life cycle than the lines marked that set `Var1`. I suggest PreRender for this purpose. Note that it should still be in a basic class. So, if _Default.aspx.cs:

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    TheControlID.Text = "Beginning of the text " & Var1 & " next of the text";

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this made your answer understandable and work. And it's the code behind that understands the & Var1 &.

Answer (score 1):

I think from your question you are trying to use that variable on the html page? If so, give this a try:

```
text = "Beginning of the text " & "<%=me.Var1.Text%>" & " next of the text"
```

Comment: yes on the html page, that's default.aspx. But it doesn't work, the message is: parser-error, the serverlabel of the radiobutton is not correct.

Comment: Can you post the html for the radio button? It should have runat="server" on it...

Comment: Its nothing special. It works without the 'break' for the variable in the text. It's runat="server" text ="... "